# Alter height when checkbox selected?

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to bind element's Height value to Checkbox.IsChecked property. Why that's not working?

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:BoolToHeightConverter x:Key="BoolToHeightConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Button Name="JustBtn" Content="Hello World"/>
      <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=JustButton, Path=Height, Converter=BoolToHeightConverter}" />


[ValueConversion(typeof(Nullable<bool>), typeof(double))]
public class BoolToHeightConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return double.NaN;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

It doesn't even initalize the window. Says:
'IValueConverter' type does not have a public TypeConverter class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems.  First, it looks like you are trying to modify the Height property when the `CheckBox` is checked.  If this is the case, you should implement your logic in the `ConvertBack` method of the converter, and specify a `Mode` on the `Binding`.  Secondly, your Binding should use a `StaticResource` to reference your converter:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=JustButton, Path=Height, Converter={StaticResource BoolToHeightConverter}, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry - my bad: I forgot to attach converter through StaticResource. 
Sorry guys...